# Magento CSS property background-image:url issue with data:image/svg+xml;base64

Tags: css, magento, base64, background-image

Magento page rendering forces the ccs property background-image:url() to add the domain and directories from the root for values that are base 64 encoded images. For example `background-image:url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,PHN2ZyB4bWxu....)`

will be rendered 
`background-image:url(http://domain.com/path-to-css/data:image/svg+xml;base64,PHN2ZyB4bWxu....)`.

I am looking for a CSS switch/setting that forces the application to recognize it is encoded data instead of a URL requiring relative completion.  This generates a 404 error for the non existent image and never renders the encoded image.

Answer (score 2):

It is a bug in Magento css and js combine, minifier.
If you turn css combine off, it will work perfectly.

How to turn on/off:
http://www.metacdn.com/speed-up-magento/combine-and-minify-js-css

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this may answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include more of the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score -1):

This is related to the doc type.  `base64 images work in html 5 doc types, i.e.  !DOCTYPE html . My magneto current configuration  !DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd`" .

Comment: Joel, does that mean that all you had to do to fix the issue was change `!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd"` to `!DOCTYPE html` ?

Comment: For future reference, this answer is incorrect. The problem has nothing to do with the doctype or indeed anything in the HTML at all. The problem is a bug in Magento's concatenation code. See workarounds here: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/14973/problem-with-data-uris-and-css-file-merge